# Tensorflow Replace values in tensor which are close to zero

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to avoid numerical instabilities in my code which contains many divisions. How can I replace small values in a tensor by a predefined numerical stabilizer?

Let the stabilizer be `EPS=1e-9`. `T` is a tensor which contains many small values which are close to zero. I want to replace all values within the interval `[-EPS,EPS]` with `EPS`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do something like:

```
 my_tensor_stable = tf.where(tf.abs(my_tensor) < EPS,
                             EPS * tf.ones_like(my_tensor),
                             my_tensor)
```

Comment: Nice! Shouldn't it be `my_tensor_stable = tf.where(tf.abs(my_tensor) < EPS, EPS * tf.ones_like(my_tensor), my_tensor)`? Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: @Samuel Thanks for the correction. I'm not sure there is anything much more efficient. Well you could replace `EPS * tf.ones_like(my_tensor)` with the more verbose `tf.fill(tf.shape(my_tensor), tf.constant(EPS, dtype=my_tensor.dtype))`, although the TensorFlow runtime may be able to optimize that itself.